# Bitwise operation with TSQL like rotation, selective bit inversion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, boolean-operations, boolean-algebra

How to do bitwise operation with TSQL.

I want to shift 1 bit towards left position. the extreme left bit should become extreme right bit as well.

```
Eg1:
Declare @a tinyint = 15
--Which is equal to 0000 1111

I need the result to be 30
--Which is equal to 0001 1110

Eg2:
Declare @a tinyint = 16
--Which is equal to 0001 0000

I need the result to be 32
--Which is equal to 0010 0000
```

Or selectively invert a bit. eg here invert 3rd bit position

```
input:  0011 0010
result: 0011 1010
```

For ease of understanding i showed the input in binary, actually the input must be an int type. Like 0001 0000 represents 16.

Comment: *"the extreme left bit should become extreme right bit as well."* So you want to rotate bits?

Comment: Why don't you just multiply by 2? a = a * 2;

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, Will it be ok for all the cases?

Comment: @Jithin: it could be an overflow if the very bit is 1, say "1000 0000"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `^` ([exclusive or](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx)) to flip a bit.  For example:

```
set @input = 15
set @bit = 4
set @result = @input ^ power(2, @bit - 1)
```

In a binary system, multiplying by two shifts all the bits one place to the left.  So you can implement a 1-bit rotation by a shift and then manually carrying the top bit to the bottom bit:

```
set @input = 128
set @result = 
    case 
    when @input & 128 > 0 then (@input ^ 128) * 2 + 1
    else @input * 2  
    end
```

[Examples at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/16626/0)